# Extraction of the differences between two graphviz graphs using gvpr

Tags: graphviz

I have two `graphviz` graphs. Let's call them `before.dot` and `after.dot`.

I want to know the differences between them. I've opened them with regular old text/source code  `diff` and there is a difference, it's not a subset and superset situation, there are nodes and edges only in `before.dot`, nodes and edges only in `after.dot` and nodes and edges that are in both. How can I process these two and produce `before-only.dot` and `after-only.dot` (even if this is two separate commands)

Reading the `graphviz` docs pointed me to the `gvpr` scripting/processing tool, which appears to be the ideal mechanism for solving this given that I would like to avoid installing additional tools.

How can I get this task done using `gvpr`?

Comment: When you say difference, are you ignoring all attributes (color, label, size, ...)  and also ignoring subgraph or cluster makeup - and only want existence/absence of nodes and edges?

Comment: I’m looking for a strait diff, so any differences at all between properties of edges or nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this because I am just starting learning about gvpr.

Years ago I did make a specific dot file differ in 'awk'
for just a particular flavor of dot files.

https://github.com/TomConlin/dipper/blob/master/scripts/deltadot.awk

I would not expect it to work in the general case but
if you are comparing a distilled semantic graph with
a previous version of itself you might get some ideas.